# After updating Xcode my Swift 3 project doesn't run correctly but builds successfully

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, alamofire

After updating my Xcode a project that was fully functional and ready for launch it now breaks at runtime but gives no errors or warnings at compile time.

I suspect that my simulator or Alamofire 4 is the problem, but I can't seem to find the reason why it's misbehaving. All I can figure out is that the Alamofire files aren't parsed correctly before given to the simulator or that the simulator is skipping the parsed Alamofire files when building.

If anyone has an idea of how to fix this please help.

This is where it breaks:

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x599c34 <+0>:  movl   $0x209, %eax              ; imm = 0x209 
    0x599c39 <+5>:  calll  0x59a3f0                  ; _sysenter_trap
->  0x599c3e <+10>: jae    0x599c4e                  ; <+26>
    0x599c40 <+12>: calll  0x599c45                  ; <+17>
    0x599c45 <+17>: popl   %edx
    0x599c46 <+18>: movl   0x10553(%edx), %edx
    0x599c4c <+24>: jmpl   *%edx
    0x599c4e <+26>: retl   
    0x599c4f <+27>: nop
```

With a message of : "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"
and in my console i get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from:         /Users/stackle005/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5D244AC3-834B-   401B-BA73-0664E95327DF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BD754A02-4BFA-    4460-9603-51C94683A286/StackleApp.app/StackleApp
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

Comment: try after deleting app from simulator

Answer (score 3):

The explanation of your error log is : "**linker found the library, but can't use it.**"

Check and Follow below steps :

1. Clear old build data from CoreSimulator,Delete apps from Simulator/device.
2. Go to **Project Setting -> Your_Target->General -> Embedded Binaries
   -> Click on + button and add your library here**

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great answer! Work great.